# Javascript - Replace substring from string where the value is between specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

So I have this string, that represents a math expression:

```
(timezone*timelapse)-time
```

Each word represents an id from an input field, and currently i was merely replacing each word with a prototype js expression to be evaled later:

```
$('timezone').value,

$('timelapse').value
```

The problem is the last id. By the time i reach it, my expression is currently like this:

```
($('timezone').value*$('timelapse').value)-time
```

So when I search for the word `time` to replace it with `$('time').value` it will affect the first two values and messing the final expression.

My question here is: How can I replace the correct word here?

Since this a math expression the word should probably be between any math symbols like this:

```
(+-/* **word** +-/*)

[empty space] **word** +-/*)

(*-/* **word** [empty space]
```

Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var newString = oldString.replace(/\btime\b/, "$('time').value")
```

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), meaning the regex only matches `time` if it's a stand-alone word, not when it's directly followed or preceded by any word characters.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick, but it goes for only the first ocurrence, how i make this for all ocurrences?
\b is a word boundary so, \bword\b what does the other / characters do at the beginning and end?

Comment: The `/` characters are regex delimiters. They simply mean `start regex` and `end regex`. Use `/\btime\b/g` to make the regex work on _all_ occurrences. (So, add a `g` after the second `/`)

Comment: nice. Also if the value time is a variable string how can i mix with the regex?this doesn't seem to be working: var test=/\+variable+\b/g

Comment: In that case you'll have to use the RegExp constructor, instead of a literal. Replace: `/\btime\b/g` with `new RegExp("/\b"+variable+"\b/", "g")`

Comment: Humm seems to be failing to find anything...strange

Comment: What's in your `variable`?

Comment: Tried this:

var str="(timezone*timelapse)-time";

var timeVal="time";
var regex=new RegExp("/\b"+timeVal+"\b/","g")
alert(str.replace(regex,"$('time').value"))

Comment: Whoops, messed up the slashes. Use this: `RegExp("\\b"+timeVal+"\\b","g")`

Comment: Thanks mate really appreciated! Also one question why do the slashes change inside the constructor?

Comment: The `/ /` are to define a regex literal (like `" "`) are used for strings. They aren't used in the `RegExp` constructor, since that constructor takes a `String` as parameter. However, for the same reason we need to escape `\` to `\\`.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace all with one replacement, then you don't have the double replacement problem:

```
exp = exp.replace(/([A-Za-z]+)/g, function(m){
  return "$('" + m + "').value";
});
```

If it's a straight replacement without any logic, you can also use the caught value in a replacement string, as Cerbrus suggested:

```
exp = exp.replace(/([A-Za-z]+)/g, "$('$1').value");
```

Comment: Your Kung-Fu is stronger than mine. +1 ... Although your style is imperfect, it can be compacted like this: `.replace(/([A-Za-z]+)/g, "$('$1').value");` :P

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes, you are right, I didn't think of that option. The callback version is useful if it needs any further expansion.